# convert Date Format yyyy-mm-dd to dd-mm-yyyy in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I have a requirement. I have a date format as `yyyy/mm/dd` and I want to convert this format to mm/dd/yyyy in action script.

I had tried to parse to this format, it is not working. Can any one of you please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var s:String = "2012/03/05";
var dateParts:Array = s.split('/'); //['2012', '03', '05']
//take off the first element and add it back at the end
dateParts.push(dateParts.shift());  //['03', '05', '2012']
s = dateParts.join('/');            //'03/05/2012'
trace(s);
```

Comment: @sch That would output 'dd/mm/yyyy' instead of the required 'mm/dd/yyyy'

Answer (score 0):

If we're opting for string manipulation, why not this:

```
'2010/05/14'.replace(/(\d{4})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})/, '$2/$3/$1')
```